# Как распарсить код с блоками if else

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Для ясности приведу пример.
Есть код

```
code{
    if(){
        if(){}
    } else {
    }
}
```

И в файле таких конструкций может быть много. Как вытащить блок кода который находится внутри `code`?

Comment: Эта задача не для регулярок, она решается другими способами.

Comment: В таком случае не подскажете какими?

Comment: Если вы собираетесь парсить код на одном из существующих языков программирования, то проще всего будет найти что-то, что строит AST (абстрактное синтаксическое дерево) для выбранного языка. А дальше уже работать с деревом.

Comment: lex +yacc вам в помощь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В комментах вам уже ответили, но для полноты.

Чтобы что-то распарсить, надо сначала определить, что может быть на входе. Один пример, как у вас в вопросе, не задает полностью возможные входы. Возможные методы решения сильно отличаются в зависимости от этого. Приведу несколько примеров:

1. Речь про код на определенном языке программирования, который может быть отформатирован произвольным образом и содержать все что угодно внутри блоков, например:

   ```
   {if(cond) { // /* if() {
     } // */
   } // блок закончился тут!
   ```

   - тогда вам нужно искать парсер и работать с AST, как предложили в комментариях.
2. Если форматирование все еще может быть произвольным, но вы готовы разбирать текст исходя из парных фигурных скобок (т.е. в коде нет непарных фигурных скобок, не задающих структуру - как, например, строки или комментария с одной скобкой `"{"`) - это может быть проще, чем разбираться с настоящим парсером. Решения на Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651487/python-parsing-bracketed-blocks
3. Форматирование не произвольное, вы можете сформулировать совсем простые правила поиска начала и конца блоков, не связанные с тем, что было внутри блока (например, блок завершается символом `}` в начале строки). Это еще проще и может решаться примерно таким псевдокодом:

   ```
   текущее состояние := вне блока
   для каждой строки исходного текста
     если находимся вне блока:
       если текущая строка обозначает начало блока:
         текущее состояние := внутри блока
         текущий блок := пустой
       иначе:
         пропускаем строку?
     иначе если находимся внутри блока:
       если текущая строка обозначает конец блока:
         вывести текущий блок
         текущее состояние := вне блока
       иначе:
         добавляем строку в текущий блок
   ```

Вот для проверок "текущая строка обозначает" могут быть полезны регулярные выражения.

А для разбора предыдущих двух кейсов классические регулярки просто по своему определению не могут быть использованы. Если интересно почему, почитайте про [формальные грамматики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) - это как раз способы задать, какой набор текста является "языком" - чем-то, что вы готовы разбирать. Вложенные скобки - пример [контекстно-свободной](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0); то что умеют разбирать классические регулярные выражения - [регулярные языки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), подмножество контекстно-свободных.

Синтаксис реальных языков программирования часто не описывается даже контекстно-свободной грамматикой, не говоря уже про регулярные, но это не останавливает народ от регулярных (pun intended) вопросов "как мне распарсить <язык программирования> с помощью регулярных выражений" - на эту тему на английском SO есть [красочный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1026) ответившего на сотню таких вопросов.

PS. как правильно отмечает ReinRaus, "регулярные выражения" сейчас имеют более широкие возможности, чем в классическом понимании. Насколько более широкие зависит от того, где вы их используете (в Perl расширенных возможностей, например, больше чем в JS). В таких случаях рекомендую помнить про [известную фразу](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) про то, что не все задачи нужно пытаться решить с помощью регулярок:

> Некоторые люди, столкнувшись с проблемой, думают: «О, а использую-ка я регулярные выражения». Теперь у них есть две проблемы.

Answer (score 6):

В-общем и целом ответ Nickolay верен, но не совсем:
Современные регулярные выражения позволяют описывать нерегулярные грамматики. Это позволяют сделать рекурсивные ссылки, которые реализованы в регулярных выражениях уже примерно лет 15-20, поэтому некорректно категорично говорить, что ими нельзя этого сделать.

Регулярные выражения- это не описание регулярных грамматик.
Регулярные выражения- это технология, которая давным давно выросла из регулярных грамматик и позволяет описывать нерегулярные грамматики.

---

Из приведенного примера не ясно что может быть внутри блоков, но если четко понимать какой текст будет на входе, то можно составить регулярное выражение, которое будет разбирать текст упрощенным способом.
Например я вижу, что текст выровнен отступами слева, а значит делаю предположение, что такое регулярное выражение успешно справится с задачей:

```
(?:\n|^)([ ]*)code\{(.*?)\n\1\}
```

То есть ищется закрывающая скобка на том же уровне, что и открывающая.

Составить правильное регулярное выражение можно только точно зная какой текст будет на входе. И если внутри может быть вся грамматика какого-нибудь языка программирования, то значит надо описать всю грамматику этого языка, а если известно, что текст будет обладать некоторыми специфичными свойствами, то это делать не обязательно, просто надо использовать эти свойства текста.

---

Чтобы не быть совсем голословным приведу пример рекурсивного регулярного выражения, которое учитывает следующие возможности:

- строковые константы `"{}"`
- однострочные комментарии `// comment`
- многострочные комментарии `/* comment */`

Посмотреть его в работе можно здесь:
https://regex101.com/r/yN6dM3/2

```
(?:
  (?P<textNode>\"(?:\\.|[^"])*+\")
  (?P<anyChar>(?:(?P>textNode)|[^\{\}]))
  (?P<singleCom>
    \/\/
    [^\n]*+
    (?:\n|$)
  ) # end singleCom
  (?P<multiCom>
    \/\*.*?\*\/
  ) # end multiCom
  (?P<balanced>
    \{
    (?:(?P>balanced)|(?P>singleCom)|(?P>multiCom)|(?P>anyChar))*+
    \}
  ) # end balanced
){0}
((?P>balanced))
```

Способ написания должен чем-то отдаленно напомнить Вам создание грамматики в каком-нибудь yacc или вроде того. Поверьте - таким способом можно задать нерегулярную грамматику.
П.С. Кому интересно- в PCRE2 вместо `(?:...){0}` появился оператор `DEFINE`.
П.П.С. Это лишь пример. Не ищите в нем баги - я их и так знаю, я лишь хотел показать как это делается.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение! Хотя все что на практике называется regexp действительно давно уже выходит за рамки классических регулярных выражений, поддержка продвинутых фич типа рекурсивности (а не простых back-references) есть далеко не во всех языках. Поэтому говоря про регулярные выражения в общем случае, позволяю себе такую категоричность.

Comment: @Nickolay надо идти в ногу со временем :) грядет время, когда поддержка PCRE2 будет во всех языках. Ах да, PCRE начинает устаревать :( В PCRE2 много вкусностей, жаль что его пока можно использовать только в Си.